# Calculating remaining time?

Tags: java

I have a time that was generated by like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUCT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
dateFormatUCT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UCT"));

String deadline = dateFormatUCT.format(new Date());
```

I've now got this as a string called deadline. I want to get the current date time again later and compare if the deadline has passed or not. If its not passed I want to calculate how much time is remaining. Is there a good in-built way of doing this already bearing in mind that the data is now a String?

TIA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `parse` method of the *same* date format you created to translate the String representation back into a date:

```
Date deadlineDate = dateFormatUCT.parse(deadline);
```

To compare if another date (say `currentDate`) has passed the deadline, it sufficient to do:

```
if(currentDate.after(deadlineDate)) {
    // deadline has passed, do something
}
```

And to get the time difference in milliseconds between them, it is sufficient to do:

```
long timeDiff = currentDate.getTime() - deadlineDate.getTime();
```

You can use methods of the `TimeUnit` class to then convert this millisecond value to other units (like days, minutes, seconds etc):

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff);
```

Comment: That's great, didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to compare two instances of Date is by using it value in milliseconds. To get the value just do..

```
Date d = new Date();
long time1 = d.getTime();
```

..later your can do the same as above and obtain the difference of time in milliseconds. If you divide that by 1000, get the seconds, again by 60 get the minutes, and so on.

Thanks!

@leo.

Comment: Can this account across different days etc? For instance the string I'm working with is: 2013-03-07 08:48:

Comment: sure, the value that returns is the number of milliseconds since jan 1st of 1970.

Comment: As a point of clarification, it's the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.  Doing that math for minutes and smaller is pretty safe.  When you get to hours, days, months and years, you're safer to use a library (like Joda, Pojava, or Calendar) to take time zones and Daylight Saving Time into account.

Comment: Maximum will be a 48 hours difference. Thanks Lemil for this too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).
It is an enhancement on the standard Java Date API and is lighter than the Calendar API.

It also has some classes dedicated for duration quantities like [Joda Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html).

I hope it helps..